# Do DataTables plugin support Jquery 3.x

Tags: jquery, datatables

Am implementing Datatables with jquery-3.1.1 but I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function even when I have placed Jquery before the datatable scripts. All the examples I have seen are using lower versions of jquery. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Exampes: [Datatable with 3.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/zohalexix/UvjnT/2084/), [Datatable with 3.2.1](http://jsfiddle.net/zohalexix/UvjnT/2085/)

Comment: Can you tell us what version of dataTable are you using?

Comment: Datatable 1.9.0

Comment: Still no luck. I have tried the latest version of Datatables but still the same problem

Comment: Then try to reproduce the problem into a website like jsfiddle. If you can't, try to create a new dummy page on your site with only a simple table to make it easier to zone-in on the problem.

Comment: Okay thanks let me try that...

Comment: By any chance you're trying to initialize the table outside of a page load event?

Comment: I finally got this to work the problem was there were two more plugins that needed to be included before the Datatable plugin....